# Differential inclusion for piecewise finite-time lyapunov function

Tags: control-theory, lyapunov-functions

For each segment of a piecewise Lyapunov function that exhibits asymptotic stability, we can utilize the LaSalle-Yoshizawa theorem and solve it using a differential inclusion. This allows us to merge all the piecewise Lyapunov functions and demonstrate that the entire system is asymptotically stable.

Now, if each segment of my piecewise Lyapunov function achieves finite-time convergence, specifically in the form of square root, how can I utilize the differential inclusion? Can you explain whether the overall system is finite-time stable? Upon searching through some resources, I found that these studies generally assume each segment to be asymptotically stable and then prove that when the function obtained through the differential inclusion exhibits square root convergence, the overall system is finite-time stable. However, if my current equations do not exhibit asymptotic stability for each segment but instead demonstrate finite-time stability, how can I prove it?

Comment: E.g. The equation (20) in  N. Fischer, R. Kamalapurkar and W. E. Dixon, "LaSalle-Yoshizawa Corollaries for Nonsmooth Systems," in IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control, vol. 58, no. 9, pp. 2333-2338, Sept. 2013, doi: 10.1109/TAC.2013.2246900.

The invoke the asymptotic stability to yield the finite time stable, I think the reason is when $|x|$ approaches $0$ and we have the solution of the Lyapunov $V(x)$ approaching $0$. So their inclusion $v$ is start from $v\in \mathcal{V} \backslash \{0\}$. But how about to show the $|x|$ and $V(x)$ is bounded and forward invariant?

Comment: Your post is unclear. Please provide equations and other mathematical supporting information. Do not cite the paper but include some of its contents in your post.

Comment: Finite time stability is a stronger notion than asymptotic stability. So finite time stability already implies asymptotic stability.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. We are now working on this problem and will submit it somewhere. 
The point is to discuss the continuity of the Lyapunov, especially at the origin. I will update this Question later